# Set, contains that returns match rather than boolean

Tags: scala, collections

I went to the effort to create myself a class whereby I have an equals method that defines an equivalence relation for which the partition sets don't have size == 1.

The class takes an absolute path and a root (also a path), these "relative paths" are equivalent if their path relative to their roots are the same. I have two sets with these in and I have ensured that all the elements in each individual set have the same root. So, according to my logic there should be one or zero element(s() in the second set that == any element in the first set.

But now I realize that I don't have the nice O(1) lookup I wanted as the Set.contains() method only returns a boolean, not the element it found!! Is there a method or collection I'm not aware of that will give me the O(1) behaviour I'm looking for (i.e. an O(1) lookup on equals, returning the equal element.)

Answer (score 2):

Redefining equality to mean something else than equality of all elements is almost always a bad idea. Scala sets assume that if two things are equal, they are interchangeable. This is not the case in your approach.

I think you will have to use a Map[T, T] instead of a Set[T] to do what you want.

Comment: I guess I'm defining a more mathematical definition of equality than most programming languages expect. In the end I ended up creating a translation function from the domain of the first set to the domain of the second set, then using contains which also gave me the behaviour that I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: Here is a mathematical definition of equality: *Given any x and y, x = y if, given any predicate P, P(x) if and only if P(y).*. If you exclude some fields of a class from equality, it is very easy to find a P for which this is not the case.

Comment: I mean yeah, sure that ties down an equivalence relation for which the partitions are unique. I've never really seen this definition of equality in programming literature before. Usually the contract for equals is stated as exactly the conditions required for an equivalence relation. It's interesting that, given that, without your stronger condition, you can't perhaps expect all the collections to behave in an optimal manner.

Answer (score 2):

This must surely have been asked before, but if so, I'm not able to find it.

There is a hole in the API here, as far as I can see.

Perhaps hope somebody can do better, but the best workaround I can find is:

```
def lookup[T](s: Set[T], x: T): Option[T] =
  s.intersect(Set(x)).headOption
```

Let's take it for a spin. First define a case class that carries extra information that doesn't affect equality:

```
scala> case class C(x: Int)(val y: Int)
defined class C

scala> C(3)(5) == C(3)(6)
res4: Boolean = true
```

Now let's try a test case:

```
scala> val s = Set(C(3)(5), C(8)(2), C(7)(6))
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[C] = Set(C(3), C(8), C(7))

scala> lookup(s, C(8)(99)).map(_.y)
res6: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Looks good.

As for whether it's O(1), it appears to me from perusing https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala that it is.

Comment: It is O(1) since 2.11. I made Set/Set operations more efficient for s.c.i.HashSet.